# Trying to install DIP (Dialup Networking) package for SLIP protocol

Tags: linux, networking, make

We are trying to interface with a wireless modem that connects to a computer via a com-port DB-9 connection. It uses SLIP in the sense that the modem hosts a SLIP server and requires the interfacing computer to connect to it as a SLIP client.

From the documentation I've read, the package`dip` seems to be the right solution. The problem though is the following:

1. It isn't bundled in modern linux distributions like it used to be,
2. I can't get the source code, found at metalab.unc.edu, to compile,
3. attempting to install the rpm also causes similar dependency issues

So, potential solutions to this problem may include:

1. Solution to #1, 2, or 3 above.
2. Using a very old distribution of Linux (not ideal at all)
3. An alternative package to `dip`. `slattach` does not appear to be a viable option for our needs.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Update**

Slackware 14 does not include `dip` by default, but does have `dip` available for download at http://packages.slackware.com. For the time being, I am going to try this route.

Comment: How come `slattach` isn't an option?

Comment: I need to retrieve a client IP address from the modem during SLIP setup. I could build a mechanism that does this (I believe it happens out-of-SLIP-band before starting SLIP) and then run `slattach` and `ifconfig` from there. However, with my latest findings (see above), I 'm going to try to run with `dip` for now which basically does just that.